# What is the "effects" returned by `aov` and `lm`?

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression, lm, anova

I would like to ask the difference between `$coefficients` and `$effects` in `aov` output.

Here the `f1` factor and the interaction `f1 * f2` are significant. I want to interpret the effect of that factor on the response and I thought that the `$effects` is what I needed.

Let’s consider the following simple following data set.

```
f1 <- c(1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0)
f2 <- c(1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1)
r <- c(80, 50, 30, 10, 87,53,29,8)
av <- aov(r ~ f1 * f2)
summary(av)
av$coefficients
av$effects
plot(f1, r)
```

It seems that the response is being increased by 48.25 units because of `f1` 
`mean(r[f1==1]) - mean(r[f1==0])`.

But I can’t really see that on `$effects` output. What does the `$effects` output really tell me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Effects are rotated response values according to the QR factorization for design matrix. Check:

```
all.equal(qr.qty(av$qr, r), unname(av$effects))
# [1] TRUE
```

Effects are useful for finding regression coefficients from QR factorization:

```
all.equal(backsolve(av$qr$qr, av$effects), unname(coef(av)))
# [1] TRUE
```

They can also be used to find fitted values and residuals:

```
e1 <- e2 <- av$effects
e1[(av$rank+1):length(e1)] <- 0
e2[1:av$rank] <- 0

all.equal(unname(qr.qy(av$qr, e1)), unname(fitted(av)))
# [1] TRUE

all.equal(unname(qr.qy(av$qr, e2)), unname(residuals(av)))
# [1] TRUE
```

So in summary, effects are representation of data at rotated domain, and is all least square regression is about.